# Cms Wont Install Right

Tags: php, html, mysql, dynamic, content-management-system

Ive been testing a cms that i'm going to try and build off and I've been getting some errors. Its showing everywhere any "dynamic" (I think thats the name for it) should be.

```
Warning: mysqli::prepare() [mysqli.prepare]: (42S02/1146): Table 'dbarr_testing.content' doesn't exist in /home/dbarr/public_html/frontcms/app/cms/models/m_cms.php on line 101
```

Here it is: http://22twenty.com/frontcms/

Hope someone can help

Denver

Comment: it shows the error clearly `dbarr_testing.content doesn't exist`

Comment: i know but im not sure how i would fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really related to IE, but rather to the installation of the cms. The error says:

```
Table 'dbarr_testing.content' doesn't exist in ...
```

This means your database isn't properly initialized. You've created the database itself (`dbarr_testing`) but not the table (`content`) that will hold the 'dynamic' data for your views.

The documentation for the cms you're using should either contain a script to do this for you or tell you how to create them. The command you need will look similar to this (but probably more elaborate):

```
CREATE TABLE content(
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  title VARCHAR(255),
  body TEXT
);
```

Comment: yea i miss wrote the name for something else!  and it doesn't so is there a way of doing it through phpadmin?

Comment: Sure as long as you know what columns the table is supposed to contain. Just create a new tabled called `content` and add the required columns. It might be a lot easier to start over though.

Comment: i haven't a clue :( where would that generally be?

Comment: You'll have to check the docs for your cms. I'm not familiar with frontcms myself. If there's no documentation you could check the install scripts themselves. But again if this makes things too complicated, it's probably much much easier to delete everything and run the install scripts again.

Comment: its not a install script. i can send ya all the files if you'd like

Comment: I won't have time to go through everything but there has to be at least some form of documentation or script to go with it that shows how to create the database. If not then you'd be best off asking the developer.